build error when attempting to use IpcRenderer
I am attempting to make my first Electron app using Angular 18. I have followed a couple of tutorials closely, but I keep getting an error message when building the app. I created a basic service to handle the IPC functionality that lets the angular UI talk to the Electron functionality.
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import {IpcRenderer} from 'electron';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class IpcService {
  private ipc: IpcRenderer | undefined;
  constructor() {
    try {
      this.ipc = window.require('electron').ipcRenderer;
    } catch (e) {
      throw e;
    }
  }

  test(): void {
    this.ipc?.send("openModal")
  }
}


the line this.ipc = window.require('electron').ipcRenderer; seems to be causing this error on build: "An unhandled exception occurred: Cannot destructure property 'routes' of '(intermediate value)' as it is undefined."
When I remove that line, the app builds and loads normally, except of course the IPC won't work. I've can't seem to find anyone else having this issue so I feel like there's something obvious I'm missing. Thanks for the help!

You need to follow the examples on the IPC docs

Have no idea why this is the case, but wrapping the window.require line in
if (typeof window !== 'undefined') {}
fixed it.
